# How to make a div that is not affected by bootstrap or materialize css

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, materialize

As title, I need to use normal form of html tag and css to design layout, but all of the elements in the body have affected by bootstrap or materialize css. Is there a method to escape those constraint?

What I want to achieve is a auto center positioning for my input field and reveal data field with angularjs, due to the input of materialize css is limited by `col`, it's hard to achieve auto positioning. It would be relatively easier to implement with normal html input tag with outer `<center>` tag.

Comment: Don't include them? You need to explain a bit more as this doesn't make a lot of sense in the context it's in

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I have edited, thanks for your remind.

Comment: I think I may be confused, why can't you add a class and style the div to your choosing?